# Query Builder как посчитать сколько раз записана одна и та же запись

Tags: mysql, sql

Задача такая:
У нас есть кое-какие записи в БД:

```
{ "id": 2, "reason": "test","reportedUser": {id:123}}
{ "id": 3, "reason": "test","reportedUser": {id:123}}
```

Юзера можно зарепортить несколько раз и разные юзеры могут репортить одного юзера. Я хочу получить запись в которой будет показано сколько раз был зарепорчен каждый юзер. Примерно ожидаю на выход:

```
{ "id": 2, "reason": "test","reportedUser": {id:123} reportedCount:2}
```

Подскажите как возможно и возможно ли реализовать) Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, reason, reportedUser, count(*) reportedCount
from table
group by id, reason, reportedUser
order by 4 desc
```

Как то так )

Comment: а можна пример под query builder typeorm если не сложно?)

Comment: Это стандартный SQL. query builder typeorm не знаю, наверное можно как то вставить этот текст

Comment: ну в любом случае спасибо